# No audio output using PCSX2

Tags: sound, alsa, emulation, pcsx2

I recently installed EmulationStation and various emulators like KegaFusion, PCSX, PCSX2. All works fine, except for PCSX2.

All works fine, except for the audio on PCSX2. I followed several guides, but I didn't find any working solution.

I don't have enough reputation to post pictures, so I'll give you my setting by text (sorry about that).
I'm using **SPU2-X 2.0.0 [libspu2x-2.0.0]** as main sound setting. In **"configuration"** i have **Interpolation** set to **4-Catmull-Rom(PS2-like/slow)**, I disabled **effects processing**. In **"Output Settings"** I set **Module** to **2-SDL Audio**, and **PortAudio API** to **0-ALSA**; **Synchronization Mode** to **TimeStretch** and **latency to 40**.

Here's also the ~/.config/PCSX2/inis/spu2-x.ini file, in case it helps:

```
[SOUNDTOUCH]
SequenceLengthMS=30
SeekWindowMS=20
OverlapMS=10
[MIXING]
Interpolation=4
Disable_Effects=1
DealiasFilter=0
FinalVolume=100
AdvancedVolumeControl=0
VolumeAdjustC(dB)=0
VolumeAdjustFL(dB)=0
VolumeAdjustFR(dB)=0
VolumeAdjustBL(dB)=0
VolumeAdjustBR(dB)=0
VolumeAdjustSL(dB)=0
VolumeAdjustSR(dB)=0
VolumeAdjustLFE(dB)=0
[OUTPUT]
Output_Module=SDLAudio
Latency=40
Synch_Mode=0
[PORTAUDIO]
HostApi=ALSA
Device=default
Wasapi_Exclusive_Mode=0
Minimal_Suggested_Latency=1
Manual_Suggested_Latency_MS=20
[DEBUG]
Global_Enable=0
Show_Messages=0
Show_Messages_Key_On_Off=0
Show_Messages_Voice_Off=0
Show_Messages_DMA_Transfer=0
Show_Messages_AutoDMA=0
Show_Messages_Overruns=0
Show_Messages_CacheStats=0
Log_Register_Access=0
Log_DMA_Transfers=0
Log_WAVE_Output=0
Dump_Info=0
Dump_Memory=0
Dump_Regs=0
Access_Log_Filename=SPU2Log.txt
WaveLog_Filename=SPU2log.wav
DMA4Log_Filename=SPU2dma4.dat
DMA7Log_Filename=SPU2dma7.dat
Info_Dump_Filename=SPU2Cores.txt
Mem_Dump_Filename=SPU2mem.dat
Reg_Dump_Filename=SPU2regs.dat
```

Comment: [Don't put answers in questions.](http://askubuntu.com/help/self-answer)

Comment: How do I do whatever that guy said? Set the output device from the mixer? Don't understand.

Comment: I was using Arch with KDE and the DE has a mixer where you can setup the audio output for every application running.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even if in the config file the Device parameter was set to default, you need to set the output device from the sound mixer. Yes, it was that easy.

Comment: How do I do whatever that guy said? Set the output device from the mixer? Don't understand.

Comment: For future reference - going to the Sound section in Settings and clicking on Applications worked for me.